# Rails nested resources and path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a nested resource:

```
def workspace
  has_many :instances
end

def instance
  belongs_to :workspace
end
```

and some nested routes

```
 resources :workspaces do 
   resources :instances do 
   end 
 end 
 resources :instances
```

That way, I can visit the following path and get the same result:

```
workspaces/1/instances 
/instances
```

On my 'view/instances/index.html.erb' I have a custom pagination link, where I reload the page with additional params.

If I am in workspaces/1/instances, the link should be:

```
= link_to "← Previous", workspace_instances_path(:param => "data")
```

But, if I am in /instances:

```
= link_to "← Previous", instances_path(:param => "data")
```

How can I have a single link_to, that works for both routes? Preferably without listing all possible cases, just a single line

Comment: "all possible cases", there's just 2 cases no?

Comment: yes, there are currently 2. I thought there could be a helper or something to generate the path

Comment: I think you'll need to write one yourself http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html  . Or simply put the logic straight into the erb file , that would work. But there's no way out of asking what action the view belongs to as far as I can see (a simple if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) lets you specify the controller and action in place of the named route. Assuming that the same controller action will handle the request you could specify the controller and action

```
link_to "previous", :controller => "instances", :action => "my_action", :data => "data"
```

Comment: Thanks, I also discovered '=link_to"previous",polymorphic_path([workspace,Instance]', but it doesn't work if additional nested resources are added. Your soluction works perfectly